How to take a Python Dictionary and Put Data Into Existing PDF?
I have code where I'm taking fields from a PDF, turning them into a list, and then into a dictionary. (I'm not sure if fields->list->dictionary is necessary or if fields->dictionary makes more sense.) Then the code cross references another dictionary I have and compares the two, updating the value of the dictionary storing PDF fields if the keys match up.
def pdf_fields_to_2d_list(pdf_fields):
    # Create a 2D list with each field title and an empty string
    two_d_list = [[field, ''] for field in pdf_fields]
    return two_d_list

pdf_fields_list = pdf_fields_to_2d_list(fields)

# write function to convert the 2D list to a dictionary
def list_to_dict(list2d):
    dictionary = {item[0]: item[1] for item in list2d}
    return dictionary

# convert the 2d list to a dictionary
original_data_dict = list_to_dict(csv)
print(original_data_dict)

print("-----------------------------") # visual seperation

ending_data_dict = list_to_dict(pdf_fields_list)
print(ending_data_dict)

# find matching keys in the two dictionaries
def update_values(dict_with_values, dict_without_values):
    for key in dict_with_values:
        if key in dict_without_values:
            if dict_without_values[key] == "":
                dict_without_values[key] = dict_with_values[key]
    return dict_without_values

updated_dict = update_values(original_data_dict, ending_data_dict)

print(updated_dict)

The code above works as expected but the issue at hand is that I am now in the process of writing the dictionary values back into the original PDF and I have several questions. The code I am using to attempt this is the following:
# iterates over each page and annotation in the page and updates its field values
def update_pdf_fields(pdf_writer, field_data):
    for page_num in range(len(pdf_writer.pages)):
        page = pdf_writer.pages[page_num]
        for field_name, field_value in field_data.items():
            if field_name in page['/Annots']:
                for annot in page['/Annots']:
                    field = annot.getObject()
                    if field.get('/T') == field_name:
                        field.update({
                            NameObject("/V"): TextStringObject(field_value)
                        })
    return pdf_writer

# Update the PDF fields
updated_writer = update_pdf_fields(writer, updated_dict)

# Save the updated PDF
with open('updated_PDF.pdf', 'wb') as output_pdf:
    updated_writer.write(output_pdf)

While the code doesn't throw any errors at the moment, I have several concerns. Firstly,I'm using pypdf which I know isn't the best for editing existing PDFs so I don't know that the code is working how I want it to. I believe the code is saving it to 'updated_PDF.pdf' which is a new file, but I want the code to save it to the existing PDF from which the PDF fields were pulled from. Also, I currently don't have code which updates the field values at the moment and I'm wondering if using a loop to update the fields which fit my criteria is the right way to go about it.
